# How are these linear algebra equations equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

From equations 3.13, 3.14, and 3.17 in [Gaussian Processes](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)

#### 3.13 and 3.14

$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla\psi(f) &= \nabla\log p(y|f) - K^{-1}f \\
\nabla \nabla\psi(f) &= \nabla \nabla \log p(y|f) - K^{-1} = -W - K^{-1} 
\end{aligned}
$$

So we have defined the derivative and the second derivative of $\psi$. The next page then goes on to explain using newtons method to find where $\nabla\psi = 0$ which makes sense, but I dont get the derivation of the iterative update in equation 3.18...

#### 3.18

$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{new} &= f - (\nabla \nabla\psi)^{-1}\nabla\psi \\
&= f + (K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (\nabla \log p(y|f) - K^{-1}f) \\
&= (K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (Wf + \nabla \log p(y|f))
\end{aligned}
$$

I can't follow the last step in this equation at all. I cannot see why the $f$ disappears in the front and somehow gets put into the last term and then $Wf$ pops up. Can anyone follow this and explain the last step of the derivation?

Comment: In what sense is it not linear algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take
$$f + (K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (\nabla \log p(y|f) - K^{-1}f),$$
and add and subtract $Wf$ inside the parentheses, i.e.
$$f + (K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (\nabla \log p(y|f) - K^{-1}f - Wf + Wf).$$
Factor $K^{-1}f - Wf = (K^{-1} + W)f$, and partially expand the parentheses:
$$f + (K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (\nabla \log p(y|f) + Wf) - (K^{-1} + W)^{-1}(K^{-1} - W)f.$$
This clearly simplifies to
$$(K^{-1} + W)^{-1} (Wf + \nabla \log p(y|f)),$$
as required.

Comment: hmm, very nice. Thank you. How did you know to add and subtract $Wf$ in that step? Was it obvious to you or did you have to fiddle around with different methods before finding that would work? Whenever a solution involves something tricky like that I can never find it on my own

Comment: It reminded me of another proof I studied, in which this kind of trick was used multiple times. So, no, I didn't have to fiddle around with it, as I had already done the fiddling previously. I guess the hint is that $K^{-1}$ is half of the inverse of the $(K^{-1} + W)^{-1}$ factor, so you experiment to see what happens if you complete that factor. Or, alternatively, try to factor out $(K^{-1} + W)^{-1}$ of the *whole* expression, which means writing $f$ as $(K^{-1} + W)^{-1}(K^{-1} + W)f$. Either way, you get the desired expression.